# Why does setTimeout(myFunction, 0) work, but running the function itself not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code should select the contents of a textarea when that textarea is selected. However, it doesn't work by itself:

```
        $("#form").focus(function() {
            $("#form").select();
        });
```

It only works when I give it a `setTimeout` of 0, like so:

```
        $("#form").focus(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#form").select();
            }, 0);
        });
```

Why is that?

Comment: Why are you running `focus()` from within `focus()` on the same element? I can't evaluate JS in my head, but doesn't this create an infinite loop?

Comment: Where in the document is this function located ? Is it in document.ready ?

Comment: @Blender, I corrected that mistake. @Ashray, this is loaded within a `if(window.$) {}` block (to make sure jquery is loaded). There doesn't seem to be other js that would interfere.

Comment: It needs to be inside of a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` block, not  `if (window.$) {...}` block.

Comment: @Blender, if I don't put it in the jquery-ready block, it loads before jquery does and I get an error (I load my js at the bottom of the page). Why would it not work as is?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first code snippet is selecting, then deselecting the text. I suspect that the text selection is being handled behind the scenes after the `focus` event is finished, and `setTimeout` executes the `select` after the event (when the behind-the-scenes stuff has already happened).

Answer (score 1):

Always remember this when dealing with this sort of thing:

Browsers are single-threaded. This is a simple model, but think of it like this: Wait for event (keystroke, mouse, touch, timer, etc.), execute scripts, update the page, over and over and over.

When you `setTimeout(func, 0)` what you're doing is telling the browser to do it *next* iteration instead of this one. So it will have time to parse the form tag. Or, if you're dealing with widths or heights, it might have time to display the item and thus calculate its width or height (instead of them being read as 0).

Probably what is happening is that something in the cascade of events that is invoked by focusing the textarea also eventually deselects its contents. By moving the selection to the next iteration, you change it from going focus, select all, unselect all to focus, unselect all, select all.